# How to use chrono to see how long my sorting algorithm takes each iteration?

Tags: c++, timing

I have to run my program a certain amount of times and want to determine the time to takes for each iteration to complete. I changed it to a smaller value to see the results but it shows me

```
0.002056
0.001183
0.000613
0.000922
0.000731
```

I'm a little unsure if this is how the results should look for bubble sort since it begins larger than the end of the results. Do these results seem accurate or am I calling my timer in a weird position?

```
if (sorting_type == 1) {
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            auto timer1 = chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
            A->BubbleSort();
            auto timer2 = chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
            chrono::duration<double, milli> duration_ms = timer2 - timer1;
            cout << duration_ms.count() << endl;
            
        }  
    }
```

Comment: Unless you are somehow unsorting the data after each iteration, then you are trying to sort sorted data which is extremely fast to do, since you essentially do nothing.

Comment: Also note that computers and compilers are really good at spotting when you do the same thing over and over. The computer's ability to correctly predict branches will go way up and it may already have your data cached. The compiler can throw out whole swathes of code if it can prove no visible effect. This is the [as-if Rule](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/as_if) and it really screws up a lot of folks benchmarking code.

Comment: @user4581301 I had no clue that compiler was able to do that. In the results shown above, I had failed to consider that the array was already sorted so @ NathanOliver was correct about it being fast since it was doing nothing. I tried it with a completely random, unsorted array but received results that kept decreasing. Does that mean that after n-iterations, the compiler will just estimate the time since it's doing the same thing?

Comment: @ratpack You need to randomize the data every iteration.  Otherwise you are measuring how long it takes to sort sorted data, which is basically 0.

Comment: You would need something like `for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) { A->Shuffle()` to mix the data back up before starting the timers and sorting. Even then, the CPU will likely have to work hard the first time loading `A` into higher-speed memory (caches) and on the subsequent iterations would simply reuse the cached data. I would expect a drop off unless you have enough data to overwhelm the caches or you have completely different memory blocks going into the sort every time.

Comment: Side note: Regarding the As-if Rule, don't think of your code as a list of instructions that the compiler will transform into machine instructions. Think of your code as a description of the behaviour you want the program to have. The compiler will then determine how to accomplish that behaviour with as little effort as it can and then transform the result into machine instructions.

Comment: @user4581301 Thank you for the help! The issue was I wasn't randomizing the array after it computed the first iteration. Added the random function inside and I'm getting the results that I need. I also noticed a longer time for the first cycle when the array is at a size of 10,000 so the CPU was definitely working harder during that first cycle.

Comment: @NathanOliver Thank you for the help! That was my issue and after adding a rand function, the results were looking a lot better.

Answer (score 1):

You are repeatedly sorting the same set of data. This leads to Bubble Sort taking way less time after the first iteration. If your data looked like this before:

```
[6,2,8,1]
```

These steps would have to happen in the first iteration:

```
 <->
[2,6,8,1]
   <->
[2,6,8,1]
     <->
[2,6,1,8]
 <->
[2,6,1,8]
   <->
[2,1,6,8]
     <->
[2,1,6,8]
 <->
[1,2,6,8]
   <->
[1,2,6,8]
     <->
[1,2,6,8]
 <->
[1,2,6,8]
   <->
[1,2,6,8]
     <->
[1,2,6,8]
```

The other iterations would all just look like this:

```
 <->
[1,2,6,8]
   <->
[1,2,6,8]
     <->
[1,2,6,8]
```

Comment: Thank you for your help! With the diagram, I had a better understanding of what my code was actually doing instead of what I thought it was doing.